# vector of functions in c++

Tags: c++, vector, functional-programming

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

I push back 10 elements to this vector so now it has 10 elements: v[0], v[1], ... ,v[9]

I have another vector:

```
std::vector<std::function<>()> v5;
```

I want to push_back() these formulas to v5: v[0]*v[1], v[0]*v[2], ...

How can I push_back() these formulas to v5 vector? Can you help me for the syntax?
I will use these formulas later in the program.

For example when I call v5[0], I want to extract v[0]*v[1] (the first pushed_back formula to v5).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you've asked this question twice already? And what's the point of storing the "formula"?

Comment: @silverfox you're right. I need to store the formulas in a vector. Then I will use those formulas in the program.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one way:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{3,4,5};

    // a vector of std::functions capturing v by reference
    std::vector<std::function<int()>> v5{
        [&v]{ return v[0] * v[1]; },
        [&v]{ return v[0] * v[2]; },
    };

    for(auto&& func : v5) {
        std::cout << func() << '\n';
    }
    
    v[0] = 10; // changing v changes the output of the formula:

    std::cout << v5[0]() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
12
15
40
```

Comment: I don't want evaluated results. I want to store the formulas.

Comment: @MehmetB. Ok, I may have misunderstood your intentions at first. I've updated the answer. Is this more what you'd like to do?